# Wordpress admin loads erratically "connection reset by peer"

Tags: admin

I've been managing an Wordpress install for several months now without issues. This morning a user notified me that they could not log in to the admin page via /wp-admin. I was not able to login from my primary computer, but found that I could login from my mobile device and laptop intermittently (sometimes it works, sometimes it does not).

On the devices that do not load the admin page, I get the following message

`Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset.`

A `curl -i -l` of the page gets: `(56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`

On some of the devices that *are* able to access the admin area only the CSS loads; I get a "request failed" for the admin js files. Other devices (my laptop) are able to navigate the admin interface as usual.

I only have 7 plugins enabled on the site, and i've tried disabling all of them to no avail. It's a production site, so i'd prefer not taking it down completely to troubleshoot. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: I've finally heard back from my host. It appears that it may be a problem on their end. I will update with details.

Comment: This looks like a local issue. Did you google the error?

Comment: Yes, I have googled this. By local do you mean local to the server? or local to my computer? I've tested this on 8+ devices (local and remote) and i'm seeing the issues on all of them.

Comment: Google results imply this is local to a machine, so I don't know what's happening in your case. Regardless, though, I don't think this is anything to do with WordPress per se.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due a brute-force attack on the Wordpress install (according to my host).